# In Hugo templates, how do you check length of JSON file array?

Tags: hugo

In Hugo, you can assign the contents of a JSON file to a template variable:

```
  {{ $json := getJSON "posts.json" }}
```

How do you check the length in a condition block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`eq`](https://gohugo.io/functions/eq/) function to compare the length:

```
{{ if (eq ($json | len) 0) }}
  no data
{{ else }}
  show posts
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `len` function to get the length:

```
{{$len := len $json}}
```